# Possible to dump sflow data to pcap format?

Tags: packet-capture, fortigate, fortinet, pcap

I want to get the packet capture from fortiet/fortigate device, to capture all traffic from it on one of its interface. For it i have enabled sflow and sent it to another ntopng server. but on ntopng , i am able to see the sflow data but is there any way i can convert/dump this data to pcap format? as i need data in pcap to analyze it.

I am able to export data to json, but can we convert sflow to pcap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, using sflowtool, we can convert any type of tcp dump data to sflow, and sflow data to tcpdump or even netflow.